# Collection inheritance java vs groovy

Tags: java, inheritance, groovy, collections

Assuming this class hierarchy:

```
class A {}
class B extends class A {}
```

The following code is not valid in Java:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Because `ArrayList<B>` is not a subtype of `List<A>`.

However, in groovy the code above does not seem to raise an error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy ignores your generics unless you annotate things with `@CompileStatic`